# Is there a way to edit the places menu in Ubuntu 12.10 gnome fallback?

Tags: gnome-panel, gnome-classic

There is applications and places menus in the gnome fallback ubuntu 12.10, What I found that I only can edit the applications menu, and there is no way to edit the places menu, in gnome 2 there is a way to edit the bookmarks in nautilus and they are changed in the places menu, its not the same in gnome 3 fallback when I add bookmarks folders it dont appear in places menu.

Is there a way to add shortcuts to folders in places menu ??

Answer (score -1):

Hover mouse pointer over the word "places"  -  control-right click  -  edit menus
might do the trick for you

Answer (score -1):

I'm also using gnome fallback, and there is a pretty easy way to do this.

Go to `~/.config/gtk-3.0/`. There you will edit a file called `bookmarks` (the only one there except for `bookmarks~`).

The syntax for adding stuff is:
`file://[Directory]`
eg. `file:///home/testUser/PersonalStuff`

The fastest way to do this is with the command `echo "file:///home/TestUser/PersonalStuff" >> ~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks`

The order entries are listed is the order they will be viewed.